# change URL via htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

how can I change this URL

[http://example.com/tag/[dir]/[dir]/](http://example.com/tag/%5bdir%5d/%5bdir%5d/)...

to

[http://example.com/tag/search/[dir]/[dir]/](http://example.com/tag/search/%5bdir%5d/%5bdir%5d/)...

for example

http://example.com/tag/44/name/445

to

### http://example.com/tag/search/44/name/445

But

if 
http://example.com/tag/search/name/445 does not change!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(tag)/((?!search/).+)$ /$1/search/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```